# If $a$ is a zero divisor of $\mathbb{F}$, then does $a$ fail to have a multiplicative inverse?

Tags: ring-theory

Let F be a ring. Show that if $a$ is a zero divisor of F, then $a$ fails to have a multiplicative inverse.

All I understand is that $ab = 1$ doesn't hold and that $ac = 0$ for some $c \in F$ holds. Basically, only the definitions, but I don't know what to do with them.

Comment: "All I understand is that ab=1 doesn't hold and that ac=0 for some c∈F holds"... You are mixing the conclusion to be proven and the hypothesis. Do you see which is which?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: If $a$ is a zero divisor with multiplicative inverse $a^{-1}$, and $b \ne 0$ satisfies $ab = 0$, then

$$b = 1 b = a^{-1} ab = ...$$

Do you see the contradiction?

Comment: Every b is 0 if a has a multiplicative inverse. So a doesn't have an inverse $a^{-1}$.

Comment: @Jossie Yes, but your quantifier isn't correct. This *particular* $b$ must be zero, giving the contradiction.